# Objects outside of Art Boards are extremely sharp

Tags: adobe-photoshop

**As shown in the picture below**, I drew a regular white brush stroke that transitions between an artboard, and the "regular" canvas below. But the problem is, why does it increase the crispness when it leaves the artboard?

This really applies to anything, I was testing it with text and it does the very same thing. Is this a feature, or bug? Or neither and I am too amateur to understand the intricate complexities of *Adobe's Photoshop CC 2019 Art Boards*?
[image]